# Is unhooking event handlers needed in ASP.NET to prevent memory leaks?

Tags: asp.net, events, memory-leaks

Coming from WinForms/WPF I've learned the hard way that not remembering to unhook event handlers can lead to memory leaks.

Does this apply to Webapps too?  It seems like when the request ends, everything (non-static) should be eligible for garbage collection.  Is that true?

I remember jumping through all sorts of hoops to ensure that events got unhooked when an object goes out of scope, especially with multi-threading going on to ensure a responsive UI.  Is all of that still necessarily in a webapp or is that one of the luxuries of working with a (mostly) RESTful model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to worry about unhooking events.  You are correct that everything non-static gets queued up for garbage collection.  The main thing to worry about is cleaning up unmanaged code.  Make sure you wrap everything implementing `IDisposable` in a `using{}` block (or manually call `Dispose()` on it).